# How to keep string with quotes?

Tags: php

If user insert this data **16" HOUSEHOLD STAND FAN AA070021A** the output should be same like this **16" HOUSEHOLD STAND FAN AA070021A**  but i only get this output 16\ HOUSEHOLD STAND FAN AA070021A, the quotes become "\" .

Before :

16\ HOUSEHOLD STAND FAN AA070021A

After :

16" HOUSEHOLD STAND FAN AA070021A

```
add_to_quote.php?product_name=16" HOUSEHOLD STAND FAN AA070021A

 <?php
  $product_name_1 = $_GET['product_name'];
  $product_name_2  = str_replace('"', "", $product_name_1);
  $product_name = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $product_name_2);
  echo $product_name;
  ?>
```

Comment: You should [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) you links.

Comment: How does the user insert that data?

Comment: <a href="add_to_quote.php?product_name=<?php echo $product_name ?>">Add To Quote</a>  ..sorry admin insert data from backend , and this page echo product name in link

Comment: @bsdnoobz using **urlencode()** is done when you encode a URL not when you decode it.

Comment: @alfasin: And? Why wasn't it done prior?

Comment: @alfasin: Did you try putting that in an anchor tag?

Comment: @bsdnoobz - I misunderstood you. That's definitely an option! (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) to your link:

```
<a href="add_to_quote.php?product_name=<?php echo urlencode($product_name) ?>">Add To Quote</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have more than one comment about your code:

1- Sanitize you inputs.
instead of:

```
$product_name_1 = $_GET['product_name'];
```

use:

```
$product_name_1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_GET['product_name']));
```

As for the quotes, one of the approaches I use and the easiest one so is to use `base64_encode()` method.

Here is an example (Which is taken from your code but the variables are treated differently):

> add_to_quote.php?product_name=16" HOUSEHOLD STAND FAN AA070021A

```
 <?php
  $product_name_1 = $product_name_1 = htmlentities($_GET['product_name']);
  $product_name_2  = base64_encode($product_name_1);
  echo $product_name_2 . "<br />";
  $product_name_3 = base64_decode($product_name_2);
  echo $product_name_3;
  ?>
```

`base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()` are awesome functions in situations like this.

Comment: `htmlentities` is not for input sanitization, it's for output escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
$product_name = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $product_name_2);
```

to:

```
$product_name = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $product_name_1);
```

worked for me.

Comment: what browser are you using? it looks fine on my chrome/FF/IE!

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_name_1 = htmlentities($row["product_name"]);
$product_name_2  = str_replace('"', "", $product_name_1);
$product_name = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $product_name_2);
```

This solution worked for me.